# Is There an Exhaustive List of All/Most Common Venial and Mortal Sins?

Tags: catholicism, sin

I would like to know if there is an exhaustive list of all common venial and mortal sins or, at least, most common venial and mortal sins. It could in a certain sense be useful. I know mortal sins are usually said to be tied to the 10 commandments one way or another, but I think it wouldn't be out of touch to have additional explicit lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [7 capital sins](https://fisheaters.com/lists.html#9), which give rise to other sins, can be [mortal](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34987):

1. Pride
2. Greed
3. Lust
4. Anger
5. Gluttony
6. Envy
7. Sloth

---

St. Thomas Aquinas's [*Summa Theologica* II-II](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS.html) devotes separate questions (collections of articles) to the following, which are or can be sins or vices; for many of them, he discusses whether they can be mortal (many of them can be):

10. [Unbelief in General](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS010.html#SSQ10OUTP1)

   11. [Heresy](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS011.html#SSQ11OUTP1)

   12. [Apostasy](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS012.html#SSQ12OUTP1)

   13. [Sin of Blasphemy, in General](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS013.html#SSQ13OUTP1)

   14. [Blasphemy Against the Holy Ghost](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS014.html#SSQ14OUTP1)

   15. [Vices Opposed to Knowledge and Understanding](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS015.html#SSQ15OUTP1)

        1. [blindness of mind](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS015.html#SSQ15A1THEP1)

        2. [dullness of sense](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS015.html#SSQ15A2THEP1)

   20. [Despair](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS020.html#SSQ20OUTP1)

   21. [Presumption](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS021.html#SSQ21OUTP1)

   34. [Hatred](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS034.html#SSQ34OUTP1)

   35. [Sloth](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS035.html#SSQ35OUTP1)

   36. [Envy](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS036.html#SSQ36OUTP1)

   37. [Discord, Which Is Contrary to Peace](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS037.html#SSQ37OUTP1)

   38. [Contention](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS038.html#SSQ38OUTP1)

   39. [Schism](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS039.html#SSQ39OUTP1)

   40. [War](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS040.html#SSQ40OUTP1)

   41. [Strife](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS041.html#SSQ41OUTP1)

   42. [Sedition](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS042.html#SSQ42OUTP1)

   43. [Scandal](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS043.html#SSQ43OUTP1)

   46. [Folly Which Is Opposed to Wisdom](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS046.html#SSQ46OUTP1)

Treatise on Prudence and Justice

53. [Imprudence](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS053.html#SSQ53OUTP1)

   54. [Negligence](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS054.html#SSQ54OUTP1)

   55. [Vices Opposed to Prudence by Way of Resemblance](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS055.html#SSQ55OUTP1)

        1. [prudence of the flesh](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS055.html#SSQ55A1THEP1)

        3. [craftiness](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS055.html#SSQ55A3THEP1)

        4. [guile](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS055.html#SSQ55A4THEP1)

        5. [fraud](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS055.html#SSQ55A5THEP1)

        6. [solicitude about temporal things](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS055.html#SSQ55A6THEP1)

        7. [solicitude about the future](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS055.html#SSQ55A7THEP1)

   59. [Injustice](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS059.html#SSQ59OUTP1)

   63. [Respect of Persons](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS063.html#SSQ63OUTP1)

   64. [Murder](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS064.html#SSQ64OUTP1)

   65. [Injuries Committed on the Person](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS065.html#SSQ65OUTP1)

        1. [mutilation of members](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS065.html#SSQ65A1THEP1)

        2. [blows](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS065.html#SSQ65A2THEP1)

        3. [imprisonment](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS065.html#SSQ65A3THEP1)

   66. [Theft and Robbery](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS066.html#SSQ66OUTP1)

   67. [Injustice of a Judge, in Judging](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS067.html#SSQ67OUTP1)

   68. [Matters Concerning Unjust Accusation](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS068.html#SSQ68OUTP1)

   69. [Sins Committed Against Justice on the Part of the Defendant](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS069.html#SSQ69OUTP1)

   70. [Injustice with Regard to the Person of the Witness](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS070.html#SSQ70OUTP1)

   71. [Injustice in Judgment on the Part of Counsel](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS071.html#SSQ71OUTP1)

   72. [Reviling](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS072.html#SSQ72OUTP1)

   73. [Backbiting](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS073.html#SSQ73OUTP1)

   74. [Tale-Bearing](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS074.html#SSQ74OUTP1)

   75. [Derision](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS075.html#SSQ75OUTP1)

   76. [Cursing](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS076.html#SSQ76OUTP1)

   77. [Cheating, Which is Committed in Buying and Selling](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS077.html#SSQ77OUTP1)

   78. [Sin of Usury](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS078.html#SSQ78OUTP1)

   92. [Superstition](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS092.html#SSQ92OUTP1)

   93. [Superstition Consisting in Undue Worship of the True God](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS093.html#SSQ93OUTP1)

   94. [Idolatry](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS094.html#SSQ94OUTP1)

   95. [Superstition in Divinations](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS095.html#SSQ95OUTP1)

   96. [Superstition in Observances](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS096.html#SSQ96OUTP1)

   97. [Temptation of God](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS097.html#SSQ97OUTP1)

   98. [Perjury](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS098.html#SSQ98OUTP1)

   99. [Sacrilege](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS099.html#SSQ99OUTP1)

   100. [Simony](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS100.html#SSQ100OUTP1)

   105. [Disobedience](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS105.html#SSQ105OUTP1)

   107. [Ingratitude](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS107.html#SSQ107OUTP1)

   108. [Vengeance](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS108.html#SSQ108OUTP1)

   110. [Vices Opposed to Truth, and First of Lying](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS110.html#SSQ110OUTP1)

   111. [Dissimulation and Hypocrisy](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS111.html#SSQ111OUTP1)

   112. [Boasting](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS112.html#SSQ112OUTP1)

   113. [Irony](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS113.html#SSQ113OUTP1)

   115. [Flattery](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS115.html#SSQ115OUTP1)

   116. [Quarreling](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS116.html#SSQ116OUTP1)

   118. [Vices Opposed to Liberality, and in the First Place, of Covetousness](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS118.html#SSQ118OUTP1)

   119. [Prodigality](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS119.html#SSQ119OUTP1)

Treatise on Fortitude and Temperance

125. [Fear](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS125.html#SSQ125OUTP1)

   126. [Fearlessness](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS126.html#SSQ126OUTP1)

   127. [Daring](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS127.html#SSQ127OUTP1)

   130. [Presumption](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS130.html#SSQ130OUTP1)

   131. [Ambition](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS131.html#SSQ131OUTP1)

   132. [Vainglory](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS132.html#SSQ132OUTP1)

   133. [Pusillanimity](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS133.html#SSQ133OUTP1)

   135. [Meanness](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS135.html#SSQ135OUTP1)

   138. [Vices Opposed to Perseverance](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS138.html#SSQ138OUTP1)

        1. [effeminacy](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS138.html#SSQ138A1THEP1)

        2. [pertinacity](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS138.html#SSQ138A2THEP1)

   142. [Vices Opposed to Temperance](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS142.html#SSQ142OUTP1)

        1. [insensibility](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS142.html#SSQ142A1THEP1)

   148. [Gluttony](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS148.html#SSQ148OUTP1)

   150. [Drunkenness](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS150.html#SSQ150OUTP1)

   153. [Lust](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS153.html#SSQ153OUTP1)

   154. [Parts of Lust](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154OUTP1)

        2. [simple fornication](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A2THEP1)

        6. [seduction](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A6THEP1)

        7. [rape](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A7THEP1)

        8. [adultery](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A8THEP1)

        9. [incest](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A9THEP1)

        10. [sacrilege](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A10THEP1) (in the sense of violating a person consecrated to God such as a priest, brother, or nun)

        11. [unnatural vice](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A11THEP1) (sodomy, masturbation, bestiality, etc.)

   156. [Incontinence](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS156.html#SSQ156OUTP1)

   158. [Anger](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS158.html#SSQ158OUTP1)

   159. [Cruelty](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS159.html#SSQ159OUTP1)

   162. [Pride](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS162.html#SSQ162OUTP1)

   163. [First Man's Sin](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS163.html#SSQ163OUTP1)

   167. [Curiosity](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS167.html#SSQ167OUTP1)

Comment: It is a list, but not exactly an exhaustive list.

Comment: @DestynationY See what I added. It's quite comprehensive.

Comment: Not bad at all I must say.